# How to install JacORB?

Tags: java, jacorb

I (maybe you too) think this is a stupid question, but I took me over 2 days for installing that. So, I post this question for help.

Looked around at their document about how to install JacORB, all I did, so far, is

- Download and unzip jacorb-3.3 binary file and apache-ant-1.9.2.
- Set some environment variables ( JAVA_HOME, JACORB_HOME, ANT_HOME, PATH).

Following this post: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/spin/projects/rtpm/CORBA_MODULES/JacORB.html

I get stuck at the step 3: Set up the orb.properties file. I can not find where the file is located.

I ignore that and go to the step 4: compile JacORB: (this issue is solved, thanks lhuang)

> cd JACORB_HOME // I get an error: The system cannot find the path specified. I'm sure that I set correctly environment variable.

Could someone please tell me a step by step tutorial for installing JacORB or give me a useful link?. All I need now is just a hello world app using JacORB instead of the standard ORB included in Java JDK.

Thank you.

Comment: In the set up you set up the JACORB_HOME to this folder:

JACORB_HOME=D:\JacORB\JacORB_2_2

does D:/JacORB/JacORB_2_2/etc/orb.properties exist?

Comment: If you are using Windows, please try `cd %JACORB_HOME%`. If you are using UNIX/Linux, please try `cd $JACORB_HOME`.

Comment: @Rawa: the file orb.properties does not exist.

lhuang: It works, thanks so much.

Comment: @Dat Could you please try to read JacORB 3.3 document (http://www.jacorb.org/releases/3.3/ProgrammingGuide.pdf)?

Comment: @lhuang: Yes, I had read that before going to the link I posted above.

Comment: Oh, I got it. My bad and stupid head. thanks all. Have fun. :)